# Can't disable Google APIs

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

From the developer console, I want to disable Google Cloud Deployment Manager API, Google Compute Engine Autoscaler API, Google Compute Engine Instance Group Manager API, Google Compute Engine Instance Groups API, Google Container Engine API. However, those API cannot be disabled.

When I disable the service, it show message to me that the api is disabled. However, after some time, they will be turned on again!

I don't use compute engine or container engine.

How can I disable those APIs?

Comment: Hi, this is just to inform you that I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Adrián I have the same exact problem. There are 7 APIs related to Google Cloud, Google Compute Engine, and Google Container Engine that it won't let me disable. I never enabled them to begin with, so I don't know why they're enabled. The only thing I remember doing was clicking on some of the menu options on the left side to see what they were, but I never enabled any APIs when doing so.

Comment: @JS1 The first time you click on a section related to Compute Engine such as VM instances, it automatically enables the necessary APIs. Remember that these APIs are free so they won't incur you any cost. Please, let me know if this is causing you an issue.

Comment: @Adrián Thanks for the info.  That must be what happened.  Right now, I'm only using 4 APIs, but there are ~3x as many enabled.  Makes it harder to see the ones I'm actually using.  I know I won't be charged but just prefer to to keep my console clean.  Hopefully, the unused APIs can be disabled in the future.

Answer (score 1):

We have received some reports about this behavior and it's being investigated.

I will update this answer when the issue is fixed.

I'd like to remark that those APIs won't incur you any cost unless you use them to perform some operations related to Google Compute Engine. Then, you wouldn't pay for the APIs themselves but for the usage of the [Compute Engine resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing).

I hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

There is a circular dependency between certain APIs and when you activate them, you can't deactivate them.

The Developers Console team is aware of this issue and they're working on making API dependencies more explicit and clear directly in the console but unfortunately there is no ETA for this.

Comment: Has this been fixed yet? Still running into issues deactivating APIs from the Google Cloud Console because of other dependent APIs.

Comment: 2020 Update: I have this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to solve this problem.

1. Go to old console api page https://code.google.com/apis/console/.
2. Disable APIs about compute engine.
3. Sign Out and re-sign in console APIs page.