# Only ask for Calendar Permission GoogleCalendar API

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

[image: I want to achieve select only Calendar permission]

I have an android application in which I am synchronizing with the google calendar API to create, read and delete events using a mobile application. When you enter a google account for the first time it is synchronized without problems, but all these permissions are activated(See picture). I would like only to have the option of active calendar and the rest disabled. How can i do this?

This is the code to request permissions:

```
    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
    private void selectGoogleAccount(){
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
            Intent intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[] { GoogleAccountManager.ACCOUNT_TYPE}, true, null, null, null, null);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.titleGetUserPermission), REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
        }
}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the simplest way to [enable and disable services](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158841?hl=en) is to use [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/?_ga=1.230155290.764085548.1501243440) web UI. Though, based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454129), there's an existing dependency between certain APIs wherein if you activate them, you can't deactivate other APIs.

However, you may want to also check [Manually managed connections](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#manually_managed_connections). This will guide you how to use the `enableAutoManage` method to initiate an automatically managed connection with automatically resolved errors. In almost all cases, this is the best and easiest way to connect to Google APIs from your Android app.

Lastly, [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) might also come in handy. This document lists the OAuth 2.0 scopes that you might need to request to access Google APIs.